# finding PDF of Y, given Y|X

Tags: binomial-distribution, density-function, uniform-distribution, conditional-expectation, compound-distributions

$$Y|X\sim Bin(X,n)$$
$$X\sim U([0,1])$$

How can I find the PDF of Y?

I know that:

$$\Bbb P(Y=k)=E_X[\Bbb P(Y=k)|X]$$

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Hint: this is a *compound distribution*, which is sometimes also called a [*mixture distribution*](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/1352).

Comment: @Xi'an, Did you just give a curt "Wrong" to someone for omitting a notational convention? Great way to welcome a new user. While we're at it--you're wrong. The correct answer is actually $$ P(Y = k) = \mathbb{E}_X [P(Y=k|X)] $$

Comment: hint: beta-binomial distribution

Answer (score 1):

$$p(y=k) = \int_0^1 p(y=k|x)p(x)dx = \binom ny \int_0^1 x^y (1-x)^{n-y} dx.$$

Since $y$ and $n$ are integers, we know via standard properties of the Beta  function that $B(\alpha, \gamma) = \int_0^1 t^{\alpha-1} (1-t)^{\gamma-1} dt = \frac{\alpha!\gamma!}{(\alpha+\gamma-1)!}$. Then by letting $\alpha = y + 1$ and $\gamma = n-y+1$ we deduce that

$$ \binom ny \int_0^1 x^y (1-x)^{n-y} dx = \binom ny B(\alpha, \gamma) = \binom nyB(y + 1, n-y+1) = \frac{n!}{y!(n-y)!}\frac{y!(n-y)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{n+1},$$

so in total the marginal distribution is

$$p(y=k) = \frac{1}{n+1},$$
a uniform distribution over the (n+1) outcomes, interestingly enough.

Comment: +1 (though we prefer to give hints and not full solutions to self-study questions). [See also here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/282347/51074)

Comment: why is it $$\binom ny$$ and not $$\binom Xk$$